# HTML target="_parent"

Tags: html, web, iframe

I am putting this Iframe up on my website. The problem is when you click the link it opens in a new tab. I would like to open it in a light box so it doesn't navigate away form my site. I tried adding target="_parent"but it didn't work. Is what I am trying to do possible?

```html
<iframe width="500" scrolling="no" height="400" frameborder="0" target="_parent" src="https://www.freemedicarereport.com/comparison_form/aaibsolutions.com?bg_color=9DB3DC&amp;cta_color=E6EBE0&amp;plan=F"> </iframe><div class="tve_iframe_cover"></div><div class="tve_iframe_cover"></div><div class="tve_iframe_cover"></div><div class="tve_iframe_cover"></div><div class="tve_iframe_cover"></div>
```

Comment: not an expert on this but typically you use target = self to open in the current window

Answer (score 1):

The `target` is a property of the **link** not of the frame containing the link.

If you want to trigger a lightbox when a link is clicked, then you need to change the link to do that.